# What changes should I make to this NN to get a better loss/epoch curve?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, overfitting, keras

I am attempting to train a neural network to fit some data with the following architecture:

```
model = Sequential()
# layer 1
model.add(Dense(7, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation='linear'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(7, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation='linear'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(7, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation='linear'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(7, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation='linear'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(7, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation='linear'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(7, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation='linear'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(7, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation='linear'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(7, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation='linear'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(7, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation='linear'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(7, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation='linear'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(7, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation='linear'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy',precision,recall,f1])

from sklearn.utils import class_weight
split_location = int(X_train.shape[0]*0.2)
X_val = X_train.iloc[-split_location:,:]
y_val = y_train[-split_location:]
X_train = X_train.iloc[:-split_location,:]
y_train = y_train[:-split_location]
class_weight = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced'
                                           ,np.unique(y_train)
                                           ,y_train)


hist = model.fit(X_train.values,y_train.values, epochs=50, batch_size=128,
          verbose=1, class_weight=class_weight, validation_data=(X_val.values,y_val.values),
            callbacks=callbacks_list, shuffle=True)
```

After training over 50 epochs the following loss/epoch curve is created:

```
Train on 5595067 samples, validate on 1398766 samples
{'val_loss': [0.16370630699260016, 0.14828306206858941, 0.15146544815120758, 0.15375939467330821, 0.15551779261887769, 0.14860120066405449, 0.15101792141452278, 0.15322067398239911, 0.14989838258384708, 0.15161947356881347, 0.15003373209527424, 0.15379652393121537, 0.14921822092317205, 0.15657513150095473, 0.15066681185591274, 0.15156379228293962, 0.15549042629966836, 0.1547642705268919, 0.14812599346522948, 0.15559401133163162, 0.15182838778070101, 0.15668203393068822, 0.15228943485377922, 0.14875309533438549, 0.15916740564597445, 0.15213683552928584, 0.15506623448426834, 0.15011504060533004, 0.14852479507366009, 0.15893954981803907, 0.16225582986438905, 0.15146525805303634, 0.15033667792805225, 0.16914694318199597, 0.16295670849446725, 0.14960898253949925, 0.15752695067403114, 0.15046651159047286, 0.15538690253535983, 0.1483665518264097, 0.15382219776837991, 0.15089750749229189, 0.15193008905261657, 0.15946591337601629, 0.15603893797274523, 0.15424115727426163, 0.16436825022268611, 0.15270022897166707, 0.15384569235792123, 0.1537987335397171], 'val_acc': [0.95998615922892039, 0.96255485191947765, 0.9625133867995076, 0.96260275128220163, 0.96269068593317253, 0.9627185676517731, 0.96273072122141945, 0.96275860294002003, 0.96285082708616021, 0.9628701298144221, 0.96290015628060732, 0.9628744193095915, 0.96291159493439216, 0.96129802983486878, 0.96176701464004699, 0.96295448988608534, 0.96196719108128159, 0.96077828600352022, 0.96234895615135052, 0.96086264607518346, 0.96104280487229454, 0.96058096922573177, 0.96123154265974442, 0.96254627292913897, 0.96046944235132969, 0.96074611478975036, 0.96051662679819216, 0.96086765048621425, 0.96188354592547998, 0.96026855099423347, 0.96037793312105102, 0.96072252256631918, 0.9611872178763281, 0.95973021935048464, 0.95958938092575885, 0.96135522310379296, 0.96018848041773963, 0.96077399650835094, 0.96052520578853073, 0.96189927407443421, 0.96037578837346638, 0.9607968738159206, 0.96054450851679263, 0.96000689178890541, 0.96036149005623528, 0.96050018373337642, 0.96025282284527935, 0.96084405826278307, 0.96028999847008001, 0.96041725349343632], 'val_precision': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 'val_recall': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 'val_f1': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 'loss': [0.11360416695320169, 0.10546536095823504, 0.10479448631859302, 0.10418981778050561, 0.1039659311605194, 0.103702686021301, 0.10357415694209053, 0.10354264359677245, 0.1034630489532956, 0.10331432841788932, 0.10321070741231013, 0.10320089277934442, 0.10320657373551526, 0.10311705857085159, 0.10292357970790854, 0.10300325969327125, 0.10297844715406301, 0.10295722614892377, 0.10284421649460301, 0.10297831909763921, 0.10270698092951876, 0.10281013161923433, 0.10273270735592134, 0.10257347440138999, 0.10265744293499827, 0.10271797601243517, 0.10261469129023201, 0.10263282053079729, 0.10261252696064917, 0.1026780428078337, 0.10255737576843736, 0.10257961111556378, 0.10256816326291465, 0.10255526256532981, 0.10240226148003012, 0.10245611412796103, 0.10231028322431224, 0.10249142625327236, 0.10232622460226415, 0.10227482178253805, 0.10252379442308171, 0.10236033192308301, 0.1024380711390645, 0.10242730016772771, 0.10227715899869497, 0.10231983227569338, 0.10240002455150068, 0.10235557845757524, 0.10230408325281737, 0.10230684331953707], 'acc': [0.97190543026548659, 0.97220140527360976, 0.97222231655132652, 0.9722621730896317, 0.972251985544067, 0.97227236063468503, 0.97229791886265871, 0.97227003715963645, 0.97221892070268778, 0.97229023352189625, 0.97229255699720052, 0.97226413910656828, 0.972257347409898, 0.97229112716624411, 0.97229023352152344, 0.97227754377241349, 0.97225895596946832, 0.97228058216231172, 0.97230345945812624, 0.97226699876897116, 0.97231632793673428, 0.9722970252188009, 0.97228004597658724, 0.97230828513746581, 0.97228951860630086, 0.97229774013441761, 0.97229416555677084, 0.97231489810626781, 0.97229309318369195, 0.972331341161777, 0.97230685530650929, 0.97233598811238542, 0.97229523793049955, 0.97232008124297364, 0.97233580938363307, 0.97232079615833467, 0.97233580938351583, 0.97231042988452898, 0.97235457591519214, 0.9723451032844771, 0.97233384336595075, 0.97232937514458473, 0.97234331599641011, 0.97232544310908164, 0.97233223480624198, 0.97233223480624198, 0.97231239590172125, 0.97235493337255841, 0.97233312845047248, 0.97234939277734644], 'precision': [0.04318607766310522, 0.082003656892638846, 0.087936882887009502, 0.096868178110347522, 0.099232165040319037, 0.1024872225549192, 0.10610526654919129, 0.10469945686933077, 0.10209030165267655, 0.10681713157497037, 0.10784432216864963, 0.1058086243439857, 0.10735499820198338, 0.1077955172680939, 0.11103456057603048, 0.11026880283592153, 0.10812456906611245, 0.10939158982633816, 0.11280831344917516, 0.1097282671019669, 0.1151799260844769, 0.11271685880418512, 0.11228861765089891, 0.11627422337500112, 0.11250900215032296, 0.11288838400694001, 0.11254026792650559, 0.11347137382598144, 0.11281784569077763, 0.1166189079019115, 0.11469443740454316, 0.11790499302841405, 0.11417370657368192, 0.11577555283141153, 0.11664178536527751, 0.11659183654036762, 0.11873162597643629, 0.11629328767139382, 0.11931309050993898, 0.11795325336546804, 0.11712817784400219, 0.11789546092726166, 0.11829428844281956, 0.11606337103263677, 0.11938934825458292, 0.11785961988148966, 0.11916553174210395, 0.11842773939231339, 0.11874878387905222, 0.12049203373247321], 'recall': [0.014118418249225056, 0.027188699049355843, 0.028828338109625453, 0.032226277240763532, 0.033168871895504236, 0.03481655664606205, 0.035325909798926393, 0.034886021392624637, 0.034452885693979196, 0.035812260258083491, 0.036267397355529793, 0.035399138008983914, 0.035810657334376439, 0.03627785279360974, 0.036985823457266746, 0.036801891997815944, 0.036603202101197038, 0.037376197971835057, 0.038004928222614275, 0.037187494096896555, 0.038622951151551253, 0.038517150244883204, 0.037908066189687749, 0.039557352710400825, 0.03739064596795276, 0.037746901196957429, 0.038091013292955604, 0.038178636542289847, 0.03817338583699121, 0.039149470615628131, 0.039315676229646913, 0.039793657080052496, 0.038753742073928746, 0.038895742302263753, 0.039518730070634445, 0.039408404945255784, 0.040252873469600312, 0.039297097320055686, 0.039975109128980661, 0.040092983292862892, 0.039883563143134244, 0.040358348552354206, 0.039881546274861554, 0.038946843964483412, 0.04038412521416164, 0.040044624047074949, 0.039948125888274684, 0.040334897428796847, 0.039770934152006179, 0.040589943225833217], 'f1': [0.019788689361876124, 0.038075473533327256, 0.040716605544493363, 0.045158392119827175, 0.046441366407507095, 0.048433459572209722, 0.049478664661813394, 0.048941300105780829, 0.048171271840957271, 0.050066211408583493, 0.050794045410133014, 0.049546916480247255, 0.050169278817597321, 0.05070490809166521, 0.051970714730447808, 0.051610791945957142, 0.051066681690763727, 0.05201127497748835, 0.053132730860649895, 0.05193339388246538, 0.054057177250475638, 0.053662245939935828, 0.052853326107522601, 0.055104750658334457, 0.052506291960626908, 0.052858761119297756, 0.053163800431813416, 0.05349706223818005, 0.053174969961761381, 0.054942966279194462, 0.054501893867254576, 0.05565957073787231, 0.054032367220186762, 0.054481634113598784, 0.055028223251572368, 0.055097892515106009, 0.056184053027325626, 0.054852237307409207, 0.056138215439582306, 0.055954590487897728, 0.055656270898052508, 0.056056122042988626, 0.055811011122665961, 0.054504431364966632, 0.056491472101880741, 0.05588381264366022, 0.055920319730667099, 0.056122723342815331, 0.055781426229239844, 0.056669717329863929]}
```

[image]

The orange line is the validation loss, the blue line is the training loss.

The data is highly imbalanced, which is why I use sklearn's class_weight as a parameter for the keras fit. X_train.shape[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNMDx.png) = 9, and there is about a 20:1 class 1:class 0 ratio. I would like to make sure that I am interpreting these results correctly. Is the model overfitting after the first epoch? What changes should I investigate to fix this?

--edit--
Sample data, where the last column is the label:

```
array([[  2.06469374e-04,   0.00000000e+00,   2.06655044e-04,
      1.96226096e-04,   1.96907098e-04,   2.10053075e-04,
      2.10123898e-04,   1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      0.00000000e+00],
   [  3.49846068e-04,   0.00000000e+00,   3.14880145e-04,
      2.84354598e-04,   2.77412037e-04,   2.72366992e-04,
      3.15133305e-04,   1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      0.00000000e+00],
   [  2.75891341e-04,   0.00000000e+00,   2.75906032e-04,
      2.83324406e-04,   2.91885604e-04,   2.86806119e-04,
      2.91927673e-04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      0.00000000e+00],
   [  2.43793426e-04,   0.00000000e+00,   2.45487050e-04,
      2.39993649e-04,   2.31220462e-04,   2.36123428e-04,
      2.23352812e-04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      0.00000000e+00],
   [  2.34510576e-04,   0.00000000e+00,   2.36527064e-04,
      2.39805622e-04,   2.73673593e-04,   3.27887228e-04,
      3.48164995e-04,   1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      0.00000000e+00],
   [  4.20302618e-03,   1.00000000e+00,   4.22147554e-03,
      4.05158454e-03,   3.81480614e-03,   3.51370801e-03,
      3.75999618e-03,   1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      0.00000000e+00],
   [  1.84195985e-03,   1.00000000e+00,   1.84103369e-03,
      1.82596633e-03,   1.78297604e-03,   1.73477764e-03,
      1.59173860e-03,   1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      0.00000000e+00],
   [  3.82165605e-04,   0.00000000e+00,   3.82886640e-04,
      3.83661466e-04,   3.81056658e-04,   4.42352200e-04,
      5.28278411e-04,   1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      0.00000000e+00],
   [  3.20170758e-04,   0.00000000e+00,   3.22507275e-04,
      2.78190104e-04,   2.51544925e-04,   2.42750940e-04,
      2.87667709e-04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      0.00000000e+00],
   [  4.91506159e-04,   0.00000000e+00,   4.90623484e-04,
      5.12634523e-04,   5.22055335e-04,   5.09645568e-04,
      5.26666801e-04,   1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      0.00000000e+00],
   [  3.12012480e-04,   0.00000000e+00,   3.09941899e-04,
      2.80847154e-04,   2.65126312e-04,   2.36698311e-04,
      2.21064672e-04,   1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      0.00000000e+00],
   [  3.61785151e-04,   0.00000000e+00,   3.54394188e-04,
      3.45296713e-04,   3.26232058e-04,   2.99172709e-04,
      2.57545017e-04,   1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      0.00000000e+00],
   [  1.58464255e-04,   0.00000000e+00,   1.39867938e-04,
      1.28589178e-04,   1.12754035e-04,   1.09689470e-04,
      1.14503132e-04,   1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      0.00000000e+00],
   [  9.02309913e-05,   0.00000000e+00,   9.02927048e-05,
      9.05077389e-05,   9.64206328e-05,   1.11902856e-04,
      1.25649507e-04,   1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      0.00000000e+00],
   [  2.29906198e-04,   0.00000000e+00,   2.30416154e-04,
      2.04080710e-04,   2.36733009e-04,   2.20505636e-04,
      2.12970947e-04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      0.00000000e+00],
   [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      0.00000000e+00,   1.20649220e-18,   3.41841829e-18,
      2.24236368e-18,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      0.00000000e+00],
   [  2.79920378e-04,   0.00000000e+00,   2.63137002e-04,
      2.29856884e-04,   2.10269492e-04,   1.80452041e-04,
      1.48066494e-04,   1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      0.00000000e+00],
   [  7.73335396e-05,   0.00000000e+00,   7.63949598e-05,
      7.44459814e-05,   7.25510862e-05,   7.19244684e-05,
      1.54948642e-04,   1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      0.00000000e+00],
   [  1.70875910e-04,   0.00000000e+00,   1.97516934e-04,
      2.07864758e-04,   2.14027707e-04,   1.83535095e-04,
      1.52931429e-04,   1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      0.00000000e+00],
   [  2.88944270e-04,   0.00000000e+00,   2.88389780e-04,
      2.87658355e-04,   2.88040997e-04,   2.36616671e-04,
      2.20929073e-04,   1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      0.00000000e+00],
   [  9.14578379e-05,   0.00000000e+00,   9.24769902e-05,
      9.29960196e-05,   8.17242560e-05,   4.00877913e-05,
      2.44654660e-05,   1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      0.00000000e+00],
   [  7.17213115e-04,   0.00000000e+00,   7.17692680e-04,
      7.16594468e-04,   7.02347153e-04,   6.46068270e-04,
      6.47387334e-04,   1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      0.00000000e+00],
   [  4.20300515e-04,   0.00000000e+00,   4.21534998e-04,
      4.26587584e-04,   4.03535119e-04,   3.62465875e-04,
      2.80704851e-04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      0.00000000e+00],
   [  5.46763464e-04,   0.00000000e+00,   5.73685876e-04,
      5.90085505e-04,   5.64427819e-04,   5.86703901e-04,
      5.85212575e-04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      0.00000000e+00],
   [  5.84046724e-03,   1.00000000e+00,   5.10520190e-03,
      2.93437589e-03,   1.88552992e-03,   1.27886209e-03,
      9.43505709e-04,   1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      0.00000000e+00],
   [  1.08108108e-03,   1.00000000e+00,   1.04567073e-03,
      1.01994504e-03,   9.89301968e-04,   9.37864581e-04,
      8.85648747e-04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      0.00000000e+00],
   [  1.07275994e-03,   1.00000000e+00,   1.10017538e-03,
      1.09289454e-03,   1.10135939e-03,   1.11373804e-03,
      1.21099638e-03,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      0.00000000e+00],
   [  2.64634584e-02,   1.00000000e+00,   2.64129615e-02,
      2.63938540e-02,   2.65509909e-02,   2.67297200e-02,
      2.05235897e-02,   1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      0.00000000e+00],
   [  4.64187542e-03,   1.00000000e+00,   4.64035301e-03,
      4.42988266e-03,   4.32223732e-03,   3.57887118e-03,
      3.35189299e-03,   1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      0.00000000e+00],
   [  9.37939659e-04,   0.00000000e+00,   9.40937167e-04,
      9.49297837e-04,   9.79787934e-04,   9.77386787e-04,
      9.94460058e-04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      1.00000000e+00]])
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide a link to the data so we can test your example. Also, the code for generating the plot would be useful to be able to know what orange is and what blue is. A [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is always nice when it concerns code (even on cross validated).

Comment: Added label for graph, added sample data - not sure if thats what you want, the dataset is not publicly available.

Comment: Is there a rationale behind the hyperparameter choices of your model? What architectures did you try, what optimisers, activation functions, etc...? What does the data represent, is it images, a sequence, audio, outputs of a random number generator? Are you aware of pre-processing? Has this data been pre-processed? It's hard to be able to help without some more information.

Comment: Each sample is from a sequence with rolling average features and some binary time based features. The binary are 1/0, and the rolling avgs are in the range [0,1], so did not preprocess anything. Hyperparameter and architectures have been trial and error, came here hoping theres a better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no expert, but I see a few things.

1) You are using an astonishing number of **linear** activation functions in a row, eleven of them.  The composite of two linear functions is just another linear function.  You aren't actually doing much (in fact, you're just doing a linear regression) until you reach your last layer, which has a sigmoid activation function.  In every neural network example I've seen, non-linear activation is used right away, starting at the top layer.  The output layer might be linear, but the input layer (almost?) never is.  (It appears you're trying to do a classification though, outputting a zero or a one, I think that a sigmoid activation on the output layer is fine for that purpose.)

2) By the time you finally reach the one sigmoid activation function you have, you're on layer 11, and you've also gone through **eleven Dropout layers!**  I have never seen an architecture this deep, with such a small number of filters (you have seven filters per layer) and so much dropout.  I calculate that any one path you might choose through your network has only a 5.4% probability of being connected.  You're regularizing your (essentially linear) model thoroughly with all that dropout, but after that much dropout -- there's not much of a model left.

3) Finally, is this Keras?  I think that you only have to specify the input_dim for the top layer when you use Keras.Sequential.  When you call Keras.Sequential.add(), Keras should automatically infer the required input dimension of the new layer from the preceding layer.  I don't know what errors you might introduce by overriding Keras' default input_dim.

My suggestion would be to start with a much simpler architecture first and compare the results to these.  Don't add dropout at first.  It may be needed, but you don't know yet.  Definitely use a non-linear activation function early.  You have a 9-dimensional input.  I usually like to start with a shallow network, with one hidden layer, with twice as many filters as I have input dimensions.  So, something like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(18, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy',precision,recall,f1])
```

Really, that's all for a start.